# How put same element on a first place in associative array, using a php?

Tags: php

I've a assoc array like `array("id"=>"1","name"=>"NiLL");` and I need to add first element in this array. My finally array must be this `array("error" => "0", "id"=>"1","name"=>"NiLL");` How I can do this, with out overwrite array?

Comment: The requirement for specific ordering seems peculiar. Can you make do without it?

Comment: Key order is arbitrary and at best in order of operation. That is if you create key `id` then key `name` the key order *should* be `id`, `name`. But that behavior is really *undefined*.

Comment: Agreed - using an array like a map negates the need for any ordering.

Comment: would an array push work here?

Comment: He might be doing a foreach afterwards which would matter in the order of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

```
function array_unshift_assoc(&$arr, $key, $val) 
{ 
    $arr = array_reverse($arr, true); 
    $arr[$key] = $val; 
    $arr = array_reverse($arr, true); 
    return count($arr); 
}
```

In this case:

```
$your_array = array("id"=>"1","name"=>"NiLL");
array_unshift_assoc($your_array, 'error', '0');
```

Comment: Its funny how good PHP decides who lives and who dies sometimes.  `if(!isset($your_array['error'])) die();`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
array_merge( array("Error" => 0), $other_array );
```

Your first parameter will be an array with the key/value you wish to insert into your other array.